# Custom TCP socket in http requests

Tags: iphone

I am using a UIWebView in an application, the problem is that I need to control the actual TCP sockets, (I need to use another socket library than the built in sockets).

I would like to use as much of the built in functions (URLRequest, URLProtocol, caches etc) as possible.

Is there any convenient way to hook in where the actual TCP socket is created as a result of HTTP requests, i.e. where I am in charge of creating the socket?

I have looked a bit at NSURLProtocol, but not sure that is what I am looking for.